# Parameter evaluation against harcoded string always return false

Tags: mysql, parameter

In Mysql workbench I am trying to make query whit parameter.

But I have strange behavior when I try to compare parameter with static strings.

Why I do not get any rows form query like this ?
When I run query , I do get header rows, but I do not get any row.
I am sure that there is rows in table calls.
Forgive me if this too obvious but I in MsSql I did this million times without issues.

```
set @kontakt ='fo' ;
select
*
from calls
where (@kontakt = 'fo');
```

Comment: "false" is not a return value for `SELECT`.  Is "false" coming from some API?

Comment: @RickJames no I did developing sproc in Mysql workbench and trick is to select all tsql code end execute then query. As Jehad said workbanch see it as two transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it and it is working as expected:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b92cd1/1

However, some clients deals with every one statement as a single transaction. Try to add all of your code to one transaction and execute it.

I tested that in MySQL client (command line in Linux) and on SQL Fiddle (Link above)